# ¿Por que mi CardView no se ve completo?

Tags: android-studio, xml, recyclerview, cardview

### La configuración de mi `CardView` es la siguiente

```
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_contactos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
```

### El cual se visualiza en un `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

### Que a su ves se manda a llamar en un `Fragment`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FragmentsDoctor.InicioFragment">

<include
    layout="@layout/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

### Los datos del `CardView` se llenan en un adapter del recycler

```
    public class Adapter_recycler_pacientes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_recycler_pacientes.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Paciente> arrayListPacientes;

    public Adapter_recycler_pacientes(ArrayList<Paciente>arrayListPacientes){
        this.arrayListPacientes = arrayListPacientes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter_recycler_pacientes.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View  view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_paciente,null,false);
        return new Adapter_recycler_pacientes.MyViewHolder(view) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter_recycler_pacientes.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.textViewNombre.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getNombreCompleto());
        myViewHolder.textViewDomicilio.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getDomicilio());
        myViewHolder.textViewPhone.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getTelefono());
        myViewHolder.textViewFechaNacimiento.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getFechaNacimiento());
        myViewHolder.textViewExpediente.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getExpediente());
        myViewHolder.textViewKey.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayListPacientes.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewNombre;
        TextView textViewFechaNacimiento;
        TextView textViewPhone;
        TextView textViewDomicilio;
        TextView textViewExpediente;
        TextView textViewKey;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_nombre);
            textViewFechaNacimiento = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewFecha_nacimiento);
            textViewPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewPhone);
            textViewDomicilio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDomicilio);
            textViewExpediente = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNumExpediente);
            textViewKey = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewKey);
        }

    }
}
```

**Mi problema es que al momento de que se visualizan se muestra a la mitad de la pantalla en lugar abarcar todo el ancho de la pantalla del mismo modo los botones del primer `CardView` no se muestran bien**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando instancias el `ViewHolder`, fijate de pasar el `viewGroup` en el segundo argumento en lugar de null:

```
View  view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
    R.layout.card_view_paciente,
    viewGroup,
    false
);
```